# Excel Script: How to get row numbers for all empty cells in column `categories` in table `transactions`

Tags: excel, vba, office-scripts

I am trying to make an Office Script to get the row numbers of all empty cells in a specific column. At this point I have this script:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {

  let transactionsTable = workbook.getTable("table_transactions");

  let emptyCatCells = transactionsTable.getColumnByName("category").getRange().getSpecialCells(ExcelScript.SpecialCellType.blanks)

}
```

I understand I get a `RangeAreas` object consisting of one or more areas, but I don't know how to get to the individual rows for the empty cells.

I tried the getAreas() method and managed to get one level closer to the actual cells, but the I got stuck for lack of understanding how to loop through.

Ultimately I'm working on this:

I have a `table_transactions` with two columns: `description` and `category`. For every row that has an empty category I want to lookup from a second table with columns `matchWord` and `matchCategory`. I'm looking if the `matchWord` is found in the `description` column (in the first table) and then I want to populate the cell in the `category` (in first table) column with the `matchedCategory` (from the second table).

With VBA I managed to get this working with this script, but it seems the `BlankCategories` Range in VBA was iteratable as an array:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim LookupRange As Range
Dim BlankCategories As Range


Set LookupRange = Sheets("Lists").Range("AutoCatReference[DescriptionText]")
Set BlankCategories = ActiveSheet.Range("Bank_Transactions[Category]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)


    If Not BlankCategories Is Nothing Then
    On Error Resume Next

        For Each BlankCategory In BlankCategories
        
            LookupCell = "H" & BlankCategory.Row
            LookupValue = Range(LookupCell).Value

            For Each LookupItem In LookupRange
                
                If InStr(1, UCase(LookupValue), UCase(LookupItem)) <> 0 Then
                    Range("I" & BlankCategory.Row) = LookupItem.Offset(0, 1).Value
                End If
                
                
            Next LookupItem
            

        Next BlankCategory
    
    End If

End Sub
```

Thank you so much for your attention. It would be so nice to get this working and also in the prcess learn a lot from your knowledge/skills.

Cheers,
Paul

Comment: It would be more efficient to load the values and loop through them.  If you need the actual RowIndex then add the table RowIndex to the loop iterator.

Comment: I've considered this approach but I was unsure with regard to the efficiency because of the (possible size of the sheet: 10000+ rows). So I thought to first get the empty cells and then continue with the rest of the logic.
Could you maybe elaborate on the part about: "add the table RowIndex to the loop iterator"? not sure I completely understand.

Comment: If you want the RowIndex relative to the Table or the Worksheet?   If you want the RowIndex relative the WOrksheet , you'll have to add the RowIndex of the table to your iterator.

Comment: It is far more efficient to load the values of a range than each individual cell of a range.

Comment: Eventually I need the value of the cell next to the empty one. That is why I thought to get its value by row number/index. If there is a better way (e.g. by offset (1 column to the left) or something else) I'd be interested to try and understand as I'm working towards matching a word from a different table  to populate the cell, as mentioned in the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls try.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let transactionsTable = workbook.getTable("table_transactions");
    let emptyCatCells = transactionsTable.getColumnByName("category").getRange().getSpecialCells(ExcelScript.SpecialCellType.blanks)
    if (emptyCatCells) {
        // Loop through areas
        for (let i = 0; i < emptyCatCells.getAreas().length; i++) {
            let areaRange = emptyCatCells.getAreas()[i];
            // Loop through cells
            for (let j = 0; j < areaRange.getCellCount(); j++) {
                let cellRange = areaRange.getCell(j, 0)
                // Get the row#
                console.log(cellRange.getRowIndex() + 1);
            }
        }
    } else {
        console.log("No blank cells")
    }
}
```

Comment: This is so cool. Very nice code. 
Thanks for helping and also thanks for helping me learn this coding pattern (I previously never understood).